# Return foreign key model from other model (not model instance)

Tags: python, django

I have model like this:

```
class B(models.Model):
    value = models.CharField(etc...)

class A(models.Model):
    name = models.Charfield(
    fk = models.ForeignKey(B, etc...)
```

I have no instance of A in my database, but I have few instances of B.
What I want to do is to get all instances of B through A model (not instance, since I have none) in Django template.
I was thinking, since model is an object, maybe we can pass it like we pass any other object and use it's attributes in some way.

*Example*

In *views.py*:

```
def my_view(request):
    B.objects.create(value=1)
    B.objects.create(value=2)
    B.objects.create(value=3)
    return render(request, 'template.html', {'model_a': A}
```

In *template.html*:

```
...
{% for b in a.fk_set.all %}
    {{ b }}
{% endfor %}
...
```

renders as

```
1
2
3
```

I understand that's wrong, because there is no A instance and db don't know that B is related to A in any way.

**Question:** Is there a way to get similar effect like I mentioned in the example?

Comment: how can you get any foreign key if the `A` object not exists ? there aren't any connection

Comment: Yep, I know that A object doesn't exist, but I have a ```A``` model which contains an information about what can by related to A. I was wondering if I can use that.

Comment: you mean you want to get all foreign key id related to the A model ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way that works in the views, but it does not work in the template.

What you need is this line:

```
foo = A.fk.field.related_model.objects.all()
```

This gives you a queryset containing all the `B` entries:

```
<QuerySet [<B: B object (1)>, <B: B object (2)>, <B: B object (3)>, <B: B object (4)>, <B: B object (5)>]>
```

But this does not show anything in the template:

```
{% for b in model_a.fk.field.related_model.objects.all %}
    {{ b }}
{% endfor %}
```

You can pass the `foo` queryset to the template and iterate over that though.